# How to get data from a incoming email and then copy data to some directory

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, email

First of all, I have some time reading this page and I find very interesting, the content also has many questions and are very entertaining.

My question is about handling my incoming mail server, no matter if you use PHP, Perl, or Python.

I do not care, what if I want is the result which should be as close to:
I send an email to update@mydomain.com, this post will add a case such as photos, then when the mail reaches the server, the server takes to process mail and copy the attached files, in this case the photos to a folder / home / public_html / photos and then, if possible notify you if it was successful or not.

In advance thank you very much. And I hope and can be done. ñ_ñ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a pipe alias in `/etc/aliases` then restart the MTA:

```
update: |/usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Then just have the script send out an email once it's done processing.

Comment: Well, now that I have added the alias to the file. How could process the mail in the script to copy the attachments to the folder / home / public_html / photos?

Comment: With any mail-processing libraries, modules, or extensions that your language has.